# Xcode offers -std=c++20 but command line clang does not

Tags: c++, xcode

I have the Xcode command line tools installed and can use `clang++` fine for versions up to C++17. In Xcode itself, I can select C++20 in the build settings:

[image]

But when I try to compile using `clang++` from the command line with this option:

```
error: invalid value 'c++20' in '-std=c++20'
note: use 'c++17' for 'ISO C++ 2017 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++17' for 'ISO C++ 2017 with amendments and GNU extensions' standard
note: use 'c++2a' for 'Working draft for ISO C++ 2020' standard
note: use 'gnu++2a' for 'Working draft for ISO C++ 2020 with GNU extensions' standard
```

What would be the reason for this inconsistency? In case it matters:

```
~/ which clang++
/usr/bin/clang++
~/ clang++ -v
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

(I also tried `clang -x c++`).

Comment: The actual option is `2a` (because apple 11.0.3 is llvm 9 and that is pre-c++20) but the gui hides that from you? Not sure what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: @dratenik That's interesting if true, because the GUI very clearly says it is using `-std=c++20` and the project builds fine with that setting.

Comment: Is it possible to see what arguments it actually uses? Some logs? try to catch it in ps?

Comment: Or is it possible that the gui is using a different version of the compiler than your command line? Is your version of Xcode the same as the command line tools?

Comment: Interesting, I dug up the log and it clearly shows the flag `-std=c++20` (which is apparently supported according to this reddit thread https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/lhcq6j/how_to_compile_to_c20/). However it is using a different path for `clang` that is a bit odd: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++` So that appears to be the issue.

Comment: for flag support: [xcode vs llvm version table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_11.x_-_13.x_(since_SwiftUI_framework)_2) - llvm 9 has 2a, llvm 10+ has 20

Comment: You didn't happen to update XCode without updating the command line tools? (`xcode-select --install` has worked for some Random Internet People with similar issues.)

Comment: @molbdnilo that was the first thing I tried, but it just reports that they are already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you have noticed, Xcode and system uses different instance of Command Line Tools. Xcode uses the one that is embedded in Xcode, and the system will use a copy located in `Library/Developer/`, which is not automatically upgraded along with Xcode.

Support of `c++20` flag is only added for later versions of `Apple Clang`, which seems like the clang embedded within your Xcode does support it, but the clang install in `Library/Developer` does not.

To force them be the same version, you might need to download it yourself from https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=command%20line%20tools, and choose the version that matches your Xcode.